# Read all the files in a series of subdirectories in Perl

Tags: perl, subdirectory, readdir

I want to create an array of all the files in a series of subdirectories, one subdirectory at a time.  My current code is returning a "Bad symbol for dirhandle" error message at the last line of this code.  What do I need to change to properly read in the files for each subdirectory into the @I1_s array?

```
my $parent = "D:/Cleaned 10Ks" ;
my ($par_dir, $sub_dir);
opendir($par_dir, $parent);
while (my $sub_folders = readdir($par_dir)) {
    next if ($sub_folders =~ /^..?$/);  # skip . and ..
        my $path = $parent . '/' . $sub_folders;
    next unless (-d $path);   # skip anything that isn't a directory
    chdir($path) or die "Cant chdir to $path $!";
    my @I1_s=readdir($path) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

`readdir` works on handles opened with `opendir`. You're using it correctly first time, but incorrectly try to feed it string with path second time.

You also might be interested in using [`File::Find`](http://p3rl.org/File::Find) instead of writing your own implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I had to use opendir again.  That solves the problem!

Answer (score 3):

It's often easier to use the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function instead of `opendir` and `readdir`. It has the advantage of ignoring the pseudo-directories `.` and `..` as well as returning paths instead of bare file names

I think your code should look something like this

```
my $parent = 'D:/Cleaned 10Ks';

while ( my $subdir = glob "$parent/*" ) {

    next unless -d $subdir;

    my @files = grep -f, glob "$subdir/*";
}
```